# Creating JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

We can create Java GUI based application using net-beans IDE and also we can create it using Notepad . Using netbeans or eclipse it is very easy . But I saw every where that every one used notepad. So I just want to know that the best way for create Java GUI application.

Comment: "*But I saw every where that every one used notepad.*" - I didn't see that.

Comment: They use note pad just for the beginner's..:)

Comment: Its not about sticking to notepad, rather its about understanding the concept a bit better. When one does everything by hand using any editor (vim, vi, emac, notepad, notepad++, JEdit, Vim(windows)), it gives you a better understanding of how things do work. So when you use an IDE, you know exactly what you doing. Contrary to that IDEs also help you in many things, like it tells you about, how one should write code, how to organize one's project and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Its better preferring some IDE like Netbeans , Eclipse since because, you can consume time in creating the gui by utilizing the features like drag and drop, in-build function support suggestion which proper demonstration of usage and syntax.

If you are developing gui from scratch using notepad, it may takes more time, one developing things in that way should be thorough knowledge in syntax and all other functionalities

The [Java Tutorials on Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) are a pretty good resource. If you don't like hand-coding your UI with Java code there are several GUI builders out there where you can lay out your UI visually and just fill in the behaviour in code-behind. E.g. [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) has such a thing and there is [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) for [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org).

Comment: don't forget to mark it as answer if this your correct requirement